# Calling HTTPS (SSL) Endpoint in Tizen Web Application

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, tizen, tizen-web-app

[image]We are calling one API which is based on SSL security (HTTPS) and the SSL certificate is configured on Server side. When we are calling that service from Tizen Web Application in Samsung watch, it’s asking a prompt dialog every time to Allow or Deny with the message “There are problems with security certificate for this site net:: ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID“.

Now if we allow the API with SSL security is working fine but the problem is this dialog appears every time when service is going to hit.

Here in the screenshot: X sign means Deny and right side means Allow

Can we have any solution to avoid this Prompt to ask for consuming the HTTPS API call.?

We already configured this below configuration in our Project config.xml file:

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
```

**App:** Tizen Web Application

**Running on:** Samsung Galaxy Watch 3

**API:** HTTPS with GET method type request

Comment: Please check if You have correct date set on the device.

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue of Tizen 5.5.0.2, in the next release of the OS it will be fixed